# HackyView Pager is not showing the correct position

Tags: android, android-viewpager, picasso

https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

i am using this library to show some photos in viewpager (HackyViewPager)

it works fine to show the pictures

but when i want to show name of proper photo that is showing it shows the wrong position name...

i'm wondering of this error

```
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter());

public class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    final String[][] sDrawables = {{"Chrysanthemum.jpg","0"},{"Desert.jpg","1"},{"Hydrangeas.jpg","2"},{"Jellyfish.jpg","3"}, {"Koala.jpg","4"},{"Lighthouse.jpg","5"},{"Penguins.jpg","6"},{"Tulips.jpg","7"} };

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return sDrawables.length;
    }

    @Override
    public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container,int position) {

        PhotoView photoView = new PhotoView(container.getContext());

        Log.i("xxx position ",position + " " + sDrawables[position][1]);

       tvImageName.setText(sDrawables[position][1]);
        Picasso.with(ViewPagerActivity.this)
                .load("http://myserver/uploads/" + sDrawables[position][0])
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.error)
               .into(photoView);

        container.addView(photoView, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        return photoView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

}
```

would you please help me to find why this work like this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the answer myself

We have to add a listener (setOnPageChangeListener) for HackyViewPager instead of adding code inside the Adapter.

```
 mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Log.i("xxx position ",position + " " + sDrawables[position][1]);
            tvImageName.setText(sDrawables[position][1]);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```